# Why are there so many namespaces in the Yii framework?

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to create my own simple framework. I already know Codeigniter and now I decided to look at Yii framework which became quite popular in the last few years.

I understand how PHP namespaces work, but I'm surprised to see that almost everything is in a different namespace in this framework. For example, `SiteController.php` looks like this:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
```

I think there might be two reasons for this:

1. Using the “composer” software to install stuff in the right place.
2. The autoloading feature – so we can know where to find a particular class.

As for #1 – I'm not interested in that. As for #2 – I want to simplify things and create one “App” namespace and then “models”, “controllers”, etc.

Is that OK, or am I missing something? Are there other benefits of using namespaces literally for everything?

Comment: You are apparently looking at [this file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/apps/basic/controllers/SiteController.php). The way it's laid out, the `yii` namespace is for the Yii framework's core classes, and the `app` namespace is for the sample application built on top of it. Beneath those top-level namespaces are subdivisions for different components.

Comment: I would recommend that you do familiarize yourself with how the Composer autoloader works, and familiarize yourself with the [PSR-4 autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) to understand how file layouts can be influenced by namespacing in a well-understood way.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - thanks, I'll read about the components in Yii and I'll see if I can do something similiar without so many namespaces:) - and yes, some time ago I did read about PSR-4 and I understand the benefits, but as I said, I'm not really interested in this. Just out of curiosity, how many times did you make use of it?

Comment: Effectively, I _always_ use PSR-4 autoloading. Most of the time, I build individual application components as reusable pieces, and use Composer to include them in different applications. It took many years for PHP developers to move in that direction, but it has been really beneficial and resulted much more sharing of code than was common in PHP before.  Have a look at the Symfony framework and Laravel - both are composed of many individual packages rather than a monolithic core. In particular, [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/composer.json)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll have to read about this PSR-4 again:)

Comment: To @Michael's comments, I'd add that Composer and the unified autoloader approach makes automation so much easier. I can push a project to Travis more easily, and I don't have to commit dependencies - Composer will just fetch them for me. Upgrading all minor versions of deps in my project is one command. Build deployments are much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason for namespaces is to avoid naming conflicts. For example, in the app I am working on at present, I have four `Process` classes - one of mine and three in Composer dependencies. Since it is unwieldy to use the Zend approach (`Library_Name_Class_Name`), namespaces help specify which class you want to use. It also means you can name your library classes without having to worry about clashes with other libraries.

As you say, helping the autoloader know where classes are stored is also a benefit. However, this is possible with the underscored naming convention too.

Once you start using namespaces, you'll find out how useful they are, and you won't want to go back to PHP 5.2! Since new projects should be written for a version of PHP no earlier than 5.4 (at the time of writing) you can start using namespaces right away.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand why we should use namespaces, and I want to use them, it's just that I want to make it simpler. You say you have 3 classes with the same name, so you have to keep it in 3 different namespaces, but isn't this as effective as creating 3 different classes in ONE namespace? Obviously in your example I understand those classes have to have the same name, but in my example, where we have one namespaces called "models" - isn't this better to create classNameA and classNameB rather than A/className and B/className ?

Comment: "isn't this as effective as creating 3 different classes in one namespace" - no, namespaces are better. Firstly, library authors don't know what naming conflicts might arise, and without namespaces they'd have to take the Zend approach, making code references very long and difficult to handle. With namespaces, you can either refer to `\Symfony\Component\Process\Process` or you can `use` it once at the start of your file, and thereafter just refer to it as `Process`. Thus you get the specificity of the underscored format, without having to use excessively lengthy names.

Comment: "in my example, where we have one namespaces called 'models' - isn't this better to create classNameA and classNameB" - well, you should avoid naming conflicts with your own classes, certainly! But I would put them in a namespace anyway, to avoid conflicts with your dependencies. That's especially the case if you are stuck with a legacy dependency that doesn't use namespaces itself.